# Sql pasar una columna varchar a filas cada caracter del varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, datatables

Necesito pasar los datos de una columna varchar : ejemplo 123 a una tabla y cada caracter del la cadena anterior deberia quedar asi :

```
1
2
3
```

los datos vienen de una tabla la cual tiene mas campos pero solo necesito hacer eso para una columna por cada registro que ya tengo.

Como podria hacer eso, solo tengo la consulta que me devuelve la columna, pero no se como pasar por cada registro, dividirlo en letra por letra y pasarlo a otra tabla una fila por cada letra.

La estructura de las tablas es la siguiente :

Tabla 1 :
ID int,Opciones varchar.
Tabla 2 (Donde pasaria cada caracter):
ID int,Opcion char.

Esto para poder sacar fila por fila cada opcion ingresada, ya que necesito hacer una logica con cada opcion antes de insertarla en la tabla 2 ejemplo si a opcion es  la 9 o la 0 no cuenta , pero si tengo 192 tengo que contar opcion 1 una ves y opcion 2 1 vez, y hay una jerarquia de padres e hijos pero las opciones solo se registra el valor.
Gracias por adelantado

Comment: ¿cuál es la estructura de las tablas? ¿Para qué quieres hacer esto?

Comment: @jachguate ya actuaize la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Con el escenario que planteas:

```
Create table tabla1 (id int, opciones varchar(10))
go
insert into tabla1(id, opciones)
values
(1,'123'),
(2,'1789'),
(3,'126');
```

Puedes implementar una función para separar caracteres.

Lo primero una función para obtener un rango de números.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
-- © Itzik Ben-Gan, SolidQ
-- For more, see 5-day Advanced T-SQL Course:
-- http://tsql.solidq.com/t-sql-courses/
----------------------------------------------------------------------

IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.GetNums', N'IF') IS NOT NULL DROP FUNCTION dbo.GetNums;
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetNums(@low AS BIGINT, @high AS BIGINT) RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
  WITH
    L0   AS (SELECT c FROM (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1) AS D(c)),
    L1   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B),
    L2   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A CROSS JOIN L1 AS B),
    L3   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 AS A CROSS JOIN L2 AS B),
    L4   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L3 AS A CROSS JOIN L3 AS B),
    L5   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L4 AS A CROSS JOIN L4 AS B),
    Nums AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rownum
             FROM L5)
  SELECT TOP(@high - @low + 1) @low + rownum - 1 AS n
  FROM Nums
  ORDER BY rownum;
GO
```

Ahora utilizando esta, puedes crear una función para separar caracteres.

```
Create Function [dbo].[ufn_TiL_SeparaEnCaracteres]
(
    @texto nvarchar(max)
)
returns table
return
(
  WITH T (oneChar) as (
    select SUBSTRING(isnull(@texto,' '),t.n,1) as l
        from (values (1))tbl(n)
       cross join dbo.GetNums
                (1,LEN(isnull(@texto,1))) t
    )
    select
        *
    from T
)      
GO
```

Teniendo las dos funciones, ya solo te queda realizar la llamada mediante el operador apply.

```
select * from tabla1 t
cross apply dbo.ufn_TiL_SeparaEnCaracteres(t.opciones)
```

[image: Resultado]

La solución pasa entonces, por aplicar lo anterior:

```
Create table tabla2 (id int, opciones char(1))
go
insert into tabla2 (id, opciones)
    select t.id, fn.oneChar from tabla1 t
    cross apply dbo.ufn_TiL_SeparaEnCaracteres(t.opciones) fn
go
select * from tabla2
```

[image: Resultado]

[String to array in SQL](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/11/09/string-to-array-en-sql-separar-cadenas-en-caracteres/)